# How can I speed up a python loop with a timestamp interval condition

Tags: python, performance, loops, optimization, conditional-statements

I have this code that is rather done in a hurry but it works in general. The only thing it runs forever. The idea is to update 2 columns on a table that is holding 1495748 rows, so the number of the list of timestamp being queried in first place. For each update value there has to be done a comparison in which the timestamp has to be in an hourly interval that is formed by two timestamps coming from the api in two different dicts. Is there a way to speed up things a little or maybe multiprocess it?

Hint: db_mac = db_connection to a Postgres database.

the response looks like this:
{'meta': {'source': 'National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, Deutscher Wetterdienst'}, 'data': [{'time': '2019-11-26 23:00:00', 'time_local': '2019-11-27 00:00', 'temperature': 8.3, 'dewpoint': 5.9, 'humidity': 85, 'precipitation': 0, 'precipitation_3': None, 'precipitation_6': None, 'snowdepth': None, 'windspeed': 11, 'peakgust': 21, 'winddirection': 160, 'pressure': 1004.2, 'condition': 4}, {'time': '2019-11-27 00:00:00', ....

```
import requests
import db_mac
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime
import time
t = time.time()

station = [10382,"DE","Berlin / Tegel",52.5667,13.3167,37,"EDDT",10382,"TXL","Europe/Berlin"]

dates = [("2019-11-20","2019-11-22"), ("2019-11-27","2019-12-02") ]
insert_dict = defaultdict(tuple)

hist_weather_list = []

for d in dates:
    end = d[1]
    start = d[0]
    print(start, end)
    url = "https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/hourly?station={station}&start={start}&end={end}&time_zone={timezone}&&time_format=Y-m-d%20H:i&key=<APIKEY>".format(station=station[0], start=start, end=end, timezone=station[-1])

    response = requests.get(url)
    weather = response.json()
    print(weather)
    for i in weather["data"]:
        hist_weather_list.append(i)

sql = "select timestamp from dump order by timestamp asc"
result = db_mac.execute(sql)

hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - t, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
print("step1 {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))

for row in result:
    try:
        ts_dump = datetime.datetime.timestamp(row[0])
        for i, hour in enumerate(hist_weather_list):
            ts1 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime(hour["time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

            ts2 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime(hist_weather_list[i + 1]["time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

            if ts1 <= ts_dump and ts_dump < ts2:

                insert_dict[row[0]] = (hour["temperature"], hour["pressure"])

    except Exception as e:
        pass



hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - t, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
print("step2 {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))


for key, value in insert_dict.items():
    sql2 = """UPDATE dump SET temperature = """ + str(value[0]) + """, pressure = """+ str(value[1]) + """ WHERE timestamp = '"""+ str(key) + """';"""
    db_mac.execute(sql2)


hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - t, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
print("step3 {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))
```

**UPDATE** the code for multiprocessing. I'll let it run the night and give an update of the running time.

```
import requests
import db_mac
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
t = time.time()



station = [10382,"DE","Berlin / Tegel",52.5667,13.3167,37,"EDDT",10382,"TXL","Europe/Berlin"]

dates = [("2019-11-20","2019-11-22"), ("2019-11-27","2019-12-02") ]
insert_dict = defaultdict(tuple)

hist_weather_list = []

for d in dates:
    end = d[1]
    start = d[0]
    print(start, end)
    url = "https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/hourly?station={station}&start={start}&end={end}&time_zone={timezone}&&time_format=Y-m-d%20H:i&key=wzwi2YR5".format(station=station[0], start=start, end=end, timezone=station[-1])

    response = requests.get(url)
    weather = response.json()
    print(weather)
    for i in weather["data"]:
        hist_weather_list.append(i)

sql = "select timestamp from dump order by timestamp asc"
result = db_mac.execute(sql)

hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - t, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
print("step1 {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))


def find_parameters(x):

    for row in result[x[0]:x[1]]:
        try:
            ts_dump = datetime.datetime.timestamp(row[0])
            for i, hour in enumerate(hist_weather_list):
                ts1 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime(hour["time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

                ts2 = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime(hist_weather_list[i + 1]["time"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

                if ts1 <= ts_dump and ts_dump < ts2:

                    insert_dict[row[0]] = (hour["temperature"], hour["pressure"])

        except Exception as e:
            pass

step1 = int(len(result) /4)
step2 = 2 * step1
step3 = 3 * step1
step4 = len(result)
steps = [[0,step1],[step1,step2],[step2,step3], [step3,step4]]


pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
pool.map(find_parameters, steps)

hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - t, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
print("step2 {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))


for key, value in insert_dict.items():
    sql2 = """UPDATE dump SET temperature = """ + str(value[0]) + """, pressure = """+ str(value[1]) + """ WHERE timestamp = '"""+ str(key) + """';"""
    db_mac.execute(sql2)


hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - t, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
print("step3 {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))
```

**UPDATE 2**
It finished and ran for 2:45 hours in 4 cores on a raspberry pi. Though is there a more efficient way to do such things?

Answer (score 0):

So theres a few minor things I can think of to speed this up a little. I figure anything little bit helps especially if you have a lot of rows to process. For starters, print statements can slow down your code a lot. I'd get rid of those if they are unneeded.

Most importantly, you are calling the api in every iteration of the loop. Waiting for a response from the API is probably taking up the bulk of your time.  I looked a bit at the api you are using, but don't know the exact case you're using it for or what your dates "start" and "end" look like, but if you could do it in less calls that would surely speed up this loop by a lot. Another way you can do this is, it looks like the api has a .csv version of the data you can download and use. Running this on local data would be way faster. If you choose to go this route i'd suggest using pandas. (Sorry if you already know pandas and i'm over explaining) You can use: df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") and edit the table from there easily. You can also do df.to_sql(params) to write to your data base. Let me know if you want help forming a pandas version of this code.

Also, not sure from your code if this would cause an error, but I would try, instead of your for loop (for i in weather["data"]).
  hist_weather_list += weather["data"] 
   or possibly 
  hist_weather_list += [weather["data"]

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Im actually calling the API just twice out of exactly that reason. The API gives me for each day 24 hourly dicts with the parameters of i.e. temperature and pressure. After the first loop I have all dicts in a list from the two date intervals. Thats all just fine until the second loop which needs very long to finish.  The condition with the timestamp comparisons has to iterate 1495748 * 24  * number of days.  The only thing I can think of is to split the number of row into the number of cores I have and multiprocess it. Is this a way to go?

Comment: Or is there a maybe a more time efficient way to convert the timestamps? From the database I get a Postgres timestamp with timezone that I convert in a timestamp. The API gives me a string which I also convert to timestamp...  With Pandas I'm familiar but I don't see where it helps me here. And prints won't either of course ;). Overall more computing power it is, im afraid of.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I was away! I hope I'm, not to late. Pandas may help just cause it could get your dates as a date object immediately. I say may, because you never know what's going on under the hood, and it could possibly be optimized (or not) for this situation. I wish I had more time to spend with you on this. Question in your for loop in the updated code where you're updating the sql. Can you update more than one row at once? Cause updating one at a time requring you to stop processing and connect to db and send things to db waiting for a response is definitely slowing it down.

Comment: No worries! Generally i deal with a lot of database stuff and yes it might be faster with multiple update cursors. But out of couriosity i already tried that after the second update. I'ts slightly faster but it seems like the bottleneck here is the timestamp conversation and the high number of iterations. I see not much to improve than switching to a more powerful system. Do you know if Pandas is  more than just standard python methods under the hood?